# compile error in qtcreator + opencv

Tags: opencv, qt-creator

I have a qtcreator+opencv project exported in another laptop that doesn't compile

```
xxx/dialog.h:63: error: cannot declare field 'Dialog::pMOG' to be of abstract type 'cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2'
```

`xxx/ note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2':
.......
.......`

But in my principal archlinux pc is all ok to compile this

I suspect for different opencv version:
in my arch version is 2.4.8 and in my laptop  version is 3.0.0 (by pkg-config --modversion opencv command....)

otherwise what?

Answer (score 0):

you're right to assume a version problem between opencv 2.4 branch and the 3.0(master) one.

the api has changed a bit there:

- in 2.4 you can just create a BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 ( on the stack or heap, no matter )
- in 3.0 you have to use a `Ptr<BackgroundSubtractorMOG2>`  , and call `createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()` to initialize it